Is there any way to resolve host network app id in Xcode
I have this issue when I try to run the app in real iPhone device
It is working good when I run it in Simulator
I tried so many ways. I configured Firebase and I think there is not problem with Firebase because when I write test notification message it is coming to both Simulator and real iPhone device as notification
I think I checked all the possible ways to solve the problem?
I have this error nw_application_id_create_self NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_GET_SIGNED_CLIENT_ID [80: Authentication error]
I think the same problem is causing this error but I cannot figure out what is that problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78765347/xcode-ios-app-will-not-load-necp-client-action-get-signed-client-id-80-aut
