Xcode - iOS app will not load - NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_GET_SIGNED_CLIENT_ID [80: Authentication error]
I have a Cordova Ionic app.
When I attempt to run the app onto my physical device (iPhone 14 Pro) via Xcode (version 15.4, 15F31d), the logs show the following error message in the logs:
nw_application_id_create_self NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_GET_SIGNED_CLIENT_ID [80: Authentication error]
The app itself just gets stuck on the splash screen when this happens. This problem seems to have appeared with no code change on my end since the last time it was working. I switched back to my production branch and attempted to build it and same issue.
Doing a quick Google Search it seems as if others are experiencing this issue as well but I don't see any solutions or even similarities between everyone out there so I figured I'd try to gather all of the reported cases and see if we could figure out a solution to this.
If you have any information on how to solve this please let me know!
Related Reports:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/experiencing-errors-lately/241278
Is there any way to resolve host network app id in Xcode
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255647899?sortBy=best
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/7522
https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenCoreLegacyPatcher/comments/1dz7f05/xcode_errors_with_opencore_mac_61_sonoma/

iv'e been hitting my head on this issue. submitting my app to the app store gets rejected because the apple agent is getting a blank page.  this is irritating.

@wmehanna ugh sorry to hear you're experiencing this as well. I still don't have a solution for this... i saw someone say downgrading cordova-plugin-idfa from version 3.0.0 to 2.1.0 fixed it for them... i don't have this plugin but it leads me to believe it's a plugin that's causing it?
Are you using cordova? Wondering if it's something to do with cordova plugins

So it looks like for my issue this error message was a red herring. The real issue was below this error message. Apparently I needed to add cordova-plugin-file to fix it. I'm not sure why I needed to add this plugin but adding it made my app work again. I still have this error message showing up but my app works at least!

Same error, i try installing cordova-plugin-file but still getting the error.
